# Foreach php variable value create while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this full of orders, each customer will have multiple orders:

```
Customer   ponumber quantity ..

customer1   234345     56
customer2   343454     34
customer1   w34234     54
customer5   332423     54
```

I'm trying to loop through each DISTINCT customer and print the corresponding orders with the following code.

```
<?php

include("php/database_connect.php");

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM orders");
  $customer = mysql_fetch_array($query);

foreach($customer as $customers)
{

echo ' <li><h1>'. $customers . '</h1></li>';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE misc='new' AND customer='$customers'       ORDER BY columnpos ASC ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

         {
         echo'  

         <li id="id_' . $row['id'] . '">
         <div class="card">

         <table>
         <tr>
         <td>' . $row['customer'] . '</td>
         <tr>
         <td>P/O: ' . $row['ponumber'] . '</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>' . $row['partnumber'] . '</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td><b>' . $row['quantity'] . '</b> x ' . $row['foil'] . '</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>' . $row['daterequired'] . '</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>' . $row['prep'] . '</td>
         </tr>
         </table>
        <input class="hiddenid" type="hidden" value="' . $row['id'] . '" />
         <input class="hiddenquantity" type="hidden" value="' .     $row['quantity'] . '" />
         <input class="hiddenpartnumber" type="hidden" value="' .   $row['partnumber'] . '" />
         <input class="hiddenfoil" type="hidden" value="' . $row['foil'] . '" />
         </div>
         </li>


         ';
         }
}
?>
```

However the above code currently prints:

```
customer1 234345
customer1 w34234

customer1 234345
customer1 w34234
```

which seems odd... its not going through each customer.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
while($customer = mysql_fetch_array($query){
```

instead of

```
$customer = mysql_fetch_array($query);

foreach($customer as $customers)
{
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved my problem. Simple, and works, I should have spotted it.

Answer (score 3):

Make only one DB query (better performance) but process the results before looping over them:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE misc='new' ORDER BY customer ASC ");

$ordersByCustomer = array(); // nested array. 1. level: customers, 2. level: orders

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    if(!array_key_exists($row['customer'], $ordersByCustomer)) {
        $ordersByCustomer[$row['customer']] = array();
    }
    $ordersByCustomer[$row['customer']][] = $row;
}

foreach($ordersByCustomer as $customer=>$orders) {
    echo ' <li><h1>'. $customer . '</h1></li>';
    foreach($orders as $order) {
        // rest of HTML code
    }
}
```

I also encourage you to use a better separation of HTML and PHP, like so, using the [*alternative syntax for control structures*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
<?php foreach($ordersByCustomer as $customer=>$orders): ?>
    <li><h1><?php echo $customer; ?></h1></li>
    <?php foreach($orders as $order): ?>
        <li id="id_<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
            <div class="card">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><?php echo $order['customer']; ?></td></tr>
                    <!-- and so forth -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Btw, you are not generating valid HTML. `li` element must be contained in `ul` or `ol` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think your operating on a much more advanced level than me, I had trouble understanding this. Thanks for pointing out the alternative syntax for control structures link, I have wondered if there was a better way of structuring php within html. Sorry, I forgot to include the rest of the code with the <ul> tags.

Comment: @Alex: If you don't understand something in code above, just comment and ask me :)

Comment: 1 DB request is better than N+1 and separate logic from view is always good idea.

Comment: ah I see, I'm making a request after each while operation, where I could make one request for everything then sort and display after. I will study your code now...

Comment: @Alex: I had a minor mistake in my code. In the last example, of course it must be `$order['customer']` as the loop is `foreach($orders as $order)`...

Comment: hehe I was just about to ask this! Thanks a lot, this is very nice code and I'm starting to understand it. Just one question.. what is the purpose of the $ordersByCustomer = array(); (second line). Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Alex: This is just for initializing `$ordersByCustomer` with an *empty* array (the same that I'm doing with `$ordersByCustomer[$row['customer']] = array();`). Otherwise I am sure you would get at least a notice when `array_key_exists($row['customer'], $ordersByCustomer)` is called the first time (because `$ordersByCustomer` would not be an array). Maybe it is not necessary but it is definitely better for maintenance in the long run...